# Pass the payment_type in ajax to another php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I was passing **payment_type** in Form as below code , it was working fine....

**before.php**  [full code in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/EkDYk0qV)

```
<?php

foreach($resulta as $row)
{ 

if (empty($row['tracking_id']))
{ 
echo "<form method='post' action='call8.php'>"; 
echo "<input type ='hidden' name='id' value='$id'> 
<input type ='hidden' name='order_id' value='".$row['order_id']."'> 
<input type ='hidden' name='payment_type' value='".$row['payment_type']."'> 
<input type='submit'> 
</form>"; 
} 
}
```

Now i am trying like below , but **payment_type is not passing to call.php** , what wrong i done here ?

**After.php**  [full code in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/GfpQAqw2)

```
<?php
$payment_type=isset($_POST['payment_type']);
?>

<input type="button" name="shipment" id="xpress" value="xpress" 
onclick="createshipmentx('<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["order_id"]; ?>')" />

<script>

function createshipmentx(orderid)
    {    
      var assignee='<?php echo $_SESSION['login_user']?>';
      $.ajax({
        url: "call.php",
        type: "POST",       
       data:'order_id='+orderid+'&assignee='+assignee,
       // here i am passing payment_Type
       payment:'payment_type='+payment_type+'&assignee='+assignee,
        success: function(data){
          if(data==1)
          {
            $("#pdfdownload").show();                       
          }         
          window.location ="/ecom1/xpress/xpressdownload.php?orderId="+orderid;

        }
      });
    }
```

**Issue** :

**Uncaught ReferenceError: payment_type is not defined**

Based on `payment_type` value, i used if [ppd] and else[cod] condition in call.php [ https://pastebin.com/Qg6wxHCf ] , so that based on condition, values will save in database, but now its saving only in ppd.... i guess payment_type is not passing properly through ajax....

Comment: here is call.php pastebin full code : https://pastebin.com/Qg6wxHCf

Comment: payment_type should also be in data in ajax.

Comment: @BryanLoresto Thanks, i changed like this `data:'payment_type='+payment_type+'&assignee='+assignee,` , but i got `Uncaught ReferenceError: payment_type is not defined`

Comment: Oh i thought the problem was in PHP, but actually , payment_type is really not defined in your code.

Comment: @BryanLoresto but i already used this `$payment_type=isset($_POST['payment_type']);` in pastebin code : https://pastebin.com/GfpQAqw2

Comment: please check https://pastebin.com/GfpQAqw2 & tell me where i need to define `payment_type` ?

Comment: @BryanLoresto Thanks for your time, i got solution....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use data:

`{order_id:orderid,assignee:assignee,payment_type:payment_type,assignee:assignee}`

and access these value in

```
call.php eg. $_REQUEST['payment_type']
```

Sample JS Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "call.php",
    type: "POST",       
    data:{order_id:orderid,assignee:assignee,payment_type:payment_type,assignee:assignee},
    success: function(data){
        if(data==1)
        {
            $("#pdfdownload").show();                       
        }         
        window.location ="/ecom1/xpress/xpressdownload.php?orderId="+orderid;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i am trying like this `data:'order_id='+orderid+'&assignee='+assignee,
   
    data:'payment_type='+payment_type+'&assignee='+assignee,` is this correct ? because it did't worked for me, still i got `Uncaught ReferenceError: payment_type is not defined`

Comment: please check https://pastebin.com/GfpQAqw2 & tell me where i need to define `payment_type` ?

Comment: you had used "data" parameter twice here, instead you need to create a single string with set of parameters being passed to PHP. And your question you had used parameter "payment:" which is not a standard $.ajax parameter. You can try method given by where data is sent in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is that you define a PHP variable `$payment_type`, but then try to access a Javascript variable `payment_type`.

The error is correct in the fact that the Javascript variable is not defined.

You must pass the variable of the PHP variable into the JS variable.

Example:

`var payment_type = "<?php echo $payment_type; ?>"`

This will print the PHP variable into a string used to define the JS variable

Comment: Thanks, is i need to use `const payment_type="<?=$payment_type?>"` in  `createshipmentx(orderid)` in JS function ?

Comment: i got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` when i used your code in function......

Comment: You may have an earlier function of PHP or JS, try with the following:

`var payment_type="<?php echo $payment_type; ?>";`

Comment: please check https://pastebin.com/GfpQAqw2 & tell me where i need to define `payment_type` ?

Comment: You can do it just after the `$payment_type=isset($_POST['payment_type']);` line.

Line 669 for example

Comment: i tried like this : `<?php 
$payment_type=isset($_POST['payment_type']);
?>
var payment_type = "<?php echo $payment_type; ?>"` but still i got this `Uncaught ReferenceError: payment_type is not defined`

Comment: the error is showing in above line : `if($orderrecords[$k]["payment_type"]=='Cash on delivery')`

Comment: Oh. It's likely a problem with the data you receive from the database then. You can print what is inside $orderrecords[$k] to be sure there is a "payment_type" attribute inside

Comment: please check : https://prnt.sc/lofuxq , seems like data is there in database, but i cant able to pass in ajax..... before in form i passed like as in question, it worked fine....

Comment: i am trying to save values in database based on `payment_Type` value.....

Answer (score 0):

you need to put all the parameters you want to pass in the data section. There is not a "payment" section in the ajax syntax

Change this:

```
 data:'order_id='+orderid+'&assignee='+assignee,
       // here i am passing payment_Type
       payment:'payment_type='+payment_type+'&assignee='+assignee,
```

to this:

```
 data:'order_id='+orderid+'&assignee='+assignee+'payment_type='+payment_type+'&assignee='+assignee,
```

and you will access payment_type correctly with your PHP code

Comment: Thanks, i got `Uncaught ReferenceError: payment_type is not defined` in line `if($orderrecords[$k]["payment_type"]!='Cash on delivery' && $pinvalue==1){$st=1;}`

Comment: but if i used only this code : `data:'order_id='+orderid+'&assignee='+assignee,` , i dont get that error....

Comment: this error is unrelated to the piece of code you showed us. The error is because the array $orderrecors does not contain that key

Comment: that's what i also throught, because i used your code in ajax : `data:'order_id='+orderid+'&assignee='+assignee,`

Comment: `The error is because the array $orderrecors does not contain that key` okay, please tell what is solution for this ?

Comment: in call.php there is not the line of code that you say is causing your error. What I see there should work  properly with this ajax set up.

Comment: if you show where the error is raised, maybe we can help. This line of code is nowhere to see in your code. Are you probably messing up with someonelse code? If you where able to write that code you wouldn't need my help to fix it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184470/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-lelio-faieta).

Comment: but when i use this code : `data:'order_id='+orderid+'&assignee='+assignee,`, i dont get any errror, after i used your code, than only i got that error.....

Answer (score 0):

once i passed the payment_Type as below, it worked for me....

```
onclick="createshipmentx('<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["order_id"]; ?>',

'<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["payment_type"]; ?>')" />
```

**script**

```
function createshipmentx(orderid,paymenttype)
  {      
    var assignee='<?php echo $_SESSION['login_user']?>';
    alert(orderid);
    $.ajax({
      url: "call.php",
      type: "POST",
      data:'orderid='+orderid+'&assignee='+assignee+'&paymentType='+paymenttype,
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        if(data==1)
        {
          $("#pdfdownload").show();

        }
```